# TypeScript: How do you create a wrapper class that has all the methods of the base class without manually declaring?

Tags: javascript, typescript

For instance, I have a base class:

```
class Base {
    void A();
    void B();
}
```

I am trying to create a subclass:

```
class Sub extends Base {
    bool canA() { ... }

    void A() { return this.canA() ? Base.A() : undefined; }
    void B() { return Base.B(); }
}
```

My goal is to make it so that subclass will override all methods in `Base` class so that the overridden method will first call `canX()` if the method is defined in the `Sub` class, and then invoke `Base.X()` if the last call returns true.

I can of course manually define those wrapper methods; however it would be nice to do it somehow automatically/programmatically. I am quite new to TypeScript, so I am sorry if my question does not make any sense. Any suggestion?

Comment: The base class code is not valid `TypeScript`. Also you try to return values in a `void` function. Does the `canA()` function have side-effects? If not, you can just try to call `.A()` directly on the sub-class. If it exists it will call it, otherwise it will call the base.

Comment: What exactly is your use case? There might be a better way to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Something like this (dynamic method calls) should be possible using a [proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's *possible*, but it's a pain. You loop through `Base.prototype`'s methods and create wrappers:

```
class Base {
    a(): void {
        // ...
    }
    b(): void {
        // ...
    }
}
class Sub extends Base {
    canA(): boolean {
        // ...
    }
    canB(): boolean {
        // ...
    }
}
const baseProto = Base.prototype as Record<string,any>;
const subProto = Sub.prototype as Record<string,any>;
for (const name of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Base.prototype)) {
    const method = baseProto[name];
    if (typeof method === "function") {
        subProto[name] = function(...args: any[]) {
            if (this["can" + name.toUpperCase()]()) {
                method.call(this, ...args);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#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-nhi6u92eyQFqJFGoyOXmVCoHmKO0MBAkmbePBST44SS1OIAGW4MH4hhECDEqE+SlHdUnnugvAMZeM7c7MGmPb7H0HqAgbsHY+ga+nAm3894p7Yy4kl4AIiR6QwAOTOC4KHZgLY3hdiSGwUOGRgkCS86oEAA) of the above plus code demonstrating it working.

Note that this code assumes:

1. The methods have lower-case names (standard in JavaScript and TypeScript), e.g. `a`, `b`
2. The "can" methods are the lower-case name capped with the "can" prefix, e.g. `canA`, `canB`
3. The methods all have `void` return types (otherwise, you do the wrapper slightly differently)

Comment: And **now** I've fixed an error where `subProto` was referring to `Base.prototype`, not `Sub.prototype`, but my example tests didn't catch it.

Comment: @HostMAX - Glad that helped! Be sure you pick up the correction I **just** made. :-)

Comment: can you provide some info on how to do it if the return is not void. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'd never generate methods (although thats possible). Instead, just check dynamically wether a method exists on the object:

```
 class Base {
   canA?: () => boolean;
   canB?; () => boolean;

   void A() {
     if(this.canA && !this.canA()) return;
   }

    void B() {
      if(this.canB && !this.canB()) return;
    }
 }
```