# How to extend/wrap/intercept/decorate a class (with custom functionality like tracing)

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator, subclass, method-modifier

### Question

What is the current (~2024) solution to extend/wrap/intercept/decorate a typescript class with additional behaviour to separate concerns?

There are various questions regarding [wrapper classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57738464/typescript-how-do-you-create-a-wrapper-class-that-has-all-the-methods-of-the-ba), various concepts like `bind` and `Proxy`, iteration of prototype functions, (deprecated) npm helpers , etc.
All of these solutions come from various 'ages' of typescript and javascript.

### What I mean

I have a business class, lets say a service:

```
class MyService{

    public async getSomething(): Promise<string> {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    public async getSomethingElse(): Promise<string> {
        return "Hello Someting else";
    }

    public async longRunningTask(): Promise<string> {
    
        let r1 = await this.getSomething();
        console.log(r1);

        let r2 = await this.getSomethingElse();
        console.log(r2);
    

        return "All done"
    }
}
```

It contains business logic and does its job.

Now I would like to extend the class by other aspects like logging or tracing. The [open telemetry](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/js/manual/#create-nested-spans) library provides sample code on how to achieve telemetry, but makes even simple services **very** hard to read or to understand.

Here would be the same service business logic with telemetry interweaved, now much more complicated, because it mixes two concerns in one location:

```
class MyServiceWithTelemetry{

    public async getSomething(): Promise<string> {
       
        return trace.startActiveSpan('getSomething', async (span) => {

            span.setAttribute("specific to getSomething", "1234");
            try
            {
                return "Hello World!";
            }
            finally{
                span.end();
            }

        });
    }

    public async getSomethingElse(): Promise<string> {
        
        return trace.startActiveSpan('getSomethingElse', async (span) => {
            
            span.setAttribute("specific to getSomethingElse", "ELSE");
            try
            {
                return "Hello Someting else";
            }
            finally{
                span.end();
            }

        });
    }

    public async longRunningTask(): Promise<string> {
    
        return trace.startActiveSpan('longRunningTask', async (span) => {

            span.setAttribute("GUID", "1234");
            try
            {
                let r1 = await this.getSomething();
                console.log(r1);

                let r2 = await this.getSomethingElse();
                console.log(r2);
            
                return "All done"
            }
            finally{
                span.end();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

There is a lot more going on here, then the business logic itself.
Everything is more nested, everything needs an additional `try ... finally` to end a span.

My intention here is to be able to add more tracing/telemetry behaviour than "just add a console.log to every method".

In other languages I probably would `extend` `MyService`, override all the methods I need with telemetry code and have them then call the base class to perform the business logic.

AFAIK ts/js is very different from compiled languages (and even from interpreted one) with no  specific `virtual members` due to dynamic dispatch, `_proto_` prototype existence, etc.

Is there a recommended ts/js native approach to the separation of concerns above?

Comment: As so often, it depends… in particular on the level of abstraction you require. If you still want to write down all the code but separate it into two classes/files, use the classic decorator pattern ("wrapper class" implementing the same interface, using inheritance if necessary). If you want to automatically wrap all existing methods, enumerate the prototype methods and patch them. If you need individual handling of individual methods, spell them out instead of using a loop (but use a helper function to avoid duplication), or use decorator syntax. In any case, don't use a `Proxy`.

Comment: @Bergi I am still unsure. Deriving seems ok from separation of concerns POV, but what if the Service already derives from a something else? Then I have to switch to prototype. The base class issue is of course not a ts-only problem. Seems like a trade-off between bad options for me

Comment: Not sure what you mean, if you subclass something it doesn't matter if that something is a derived class itself or not. But personally I would avoid inheritance here anyway and prefer composition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP'S main problem seems to be, finding a way of how to augment already implemented functionality with the least possible code repetition and the least possible effort. Especially the OP's tracing example shows that once in a while developers are in need of reliable ***method-modifier*** abstractions which do wrap additional code around other functions/methods in ways that could be described as [`around`](https://github.com/petsel/es-function-modifiers/blob/main/src/modifiers/around/index.js#L12), [`before`](https://github.com/petsel/es-function-modifiers/blob/main/src/modifiers/before/index.js#L12), [`after`](https://github.com/petsel/es-function-modifiers/blob/main/src/modifiers/after/index.js#L14), [`afterThrowing`](https://github.com/petsel/es-function-modifiers/blob/main/src/modifiers/afterThrowing/index.js#L12) and [`afterFinally`](https://github.com/petsel/es-function-modifiers/blob/main/src/modifiers/afterFinally/index.js#L12). Such modifiers in addition need to reliably deal with method-context and asynchronism.

**Note** ... method-modification has nothing to do with Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) because the former lacks any of the latter's necessary abstraction layers which are `Joinpoint`, `Pointcut` and `Advice`.

A very quick implementation tries to demonstrate possible implementations of `around` and `afterThrowing` (at `Function.prototype`) together with just one possible way of theirs usage ...

... here as **around**-handler functions, which each target a special `MyService`-method and implement the method's additional **trace**-specific functionality around its related, but already modified, `MyService`-method. This other modification did wrap the targeted original `MyService`-method into *try-catch* functionality.

```js
async function traceGetSomething(proceed, handler, args) {
  return trace.startActiveSpan('getSomething', async (span) => {

    span.setAttribute('specific to getSomething', '1234');

    // - a modified version of the original `getSomething` method
    //   wrapped into try-catch functionality which always returns.
    // - the `result` value will be either `getSomething`'s return
    //   value or whatever value the exception handler returns.
    const result = await proceed(args);

    span.end();

    return result;
  });
}
async function traceGetSomethingElse(proceed, handler, args) {
  return trace.startActiveSpan('getSomethingElse', async (span) => {

    span.setAttribute('specific to getSomething', 'ELSE');

    const result = await proceed(args);
    span.end();

    return result;
  });
}
async function traceLongRunningTask(proceed, handler, args) {
  return trace.startActiveSpan('longRunningTask', async (span) => {

    span.setAttribute('GUID', '1234');

    const result = await proceed(args);
    span.end();

    return result;
  });
}
async function handleException(exception, args) {
  // - within a service's `this` context
  //   implement the handling of `exception`.
}

// - facory function which provides glue-code
//   for the creation of a `MyService` instance
//   with wrapped around error handling and
//   tracing behavior.
function createTelemetryTracingService() {
  const service = new MyService;

  service.getSomething = service.getSomething
    .afterThrowing(handleException, service)
    .around(traceGetSomething, service);

  service.getSomethingElse = service.getSomethingElse
    .afterThrowing(handleException, service)
    .around(traceGetSomethingElse, service);

  service.longRunningTask = service.longRunningTask
    .afterThrowing(handleException, service)
    .around(traceLongRunningTask, service);

  return service;
}


(async () => {
  console.log('+++ MyService Test Start +++');

  const service = new MyService();

  const something = await service.getSomething();
  const somethingElse = await service.getSomethingElse();

  const longRunningResult = await service.longRunningTask();

  console.log({
    something, somethingElse, longRunningResult,
  });
  console.log('+++ MyService Test End +++\n\n');


  console.log('\n+++ TracingService Test Start +++');

  const tracingService = createTelemetryTracingService();

  const somethingTraced = await tracingService.getSomething();
  const somethingElseTraced = await tracingService.getSomethingElse();

  const longRunningResultTraced = await tracingService.longRunningTask();

  console.log({
    somethingTraced, somethingElseTraced, longRunningResultTraced,
  });
  console.log('+++ TracingService Test End +++');
})();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
// module ... 'utils'

function getInternalTypeSignature(value) {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(value).trim();
}

function getFunctionSignature(value) {
  return Function.prototype.toString.call(value).trim();
}
function getFunctionName(value) {
  return Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(value, 'name').value;
  // return value.name;
}

function getInternalTypeName(value) {
  const regXInternalTypeName = /^\[object\s+(?<name>.*)]$/;

  let { name } = regXInternalTypeName.exec(
    getInternalTypeSignature(value),
  )?.groups;

  if (name === 'Object') {
    const { constructor } = Object.getPrototypeOf(value);
    if (
      typeof constructor === 'function' &&
      getFunctionSignature(constructor).startsWith('class ')
    ) {
      name = getFunctionName(constructor);
    }
  } else if (name === 'Error') {
    name = getFunctionName(Object.getPrototypeOf(value).constructor);
  }
  return name;
}

function isFunction(value) {
  return (
    typeof value === 'function' &&
    typeof value.call === 'function' &&
    typeof value.apply === 'function'
  );
}

function isAsyncType(value) {
  const typeName = !!value && getInternalTypeName(value);
  return (
    typeName &&
    (typeName === 'AsyncFunction' || typeName === 'AsyncGeneratorFunction')
  );
}
</script>

<script>
// module ... 'modifier/around'

function around(handler, target) {
  const context = target ?? null;
  const proceed = this;

  return (
    isFunction(handler) &&
    isFunction(proceed) && (

      (isAsyncType(handler) || isAsyncType(proceed)) && (

        async function aroundType(...argumentArray) {
          return await handler.call(
            context,
            proceed,
            handler,
            argumentArray,
          );
        }
      ) || (
        function aroundType(...argumentArray) {
          return handler.call(
            context,
            proceed,
            handler,
            argumentArray,
          );
        }
      )
    )
  ) || proceed;
}

Reflect.defineProperty(Function.prototype, 'around', {
  configurable: true,
  writable: true,
  value: around,
});
</script>

<script>
// module ... 'modifier/afterThrowing'

function afterThrowing(handler, target) {
  const context = target ?? null;
  const proceed = this;

  return (
    isFunction(handler) &&
    isFunction(proceed) && (

      (isAsyncType(handler) || isAsyncType(proceed)) && (

        async function afterThrowingType(...argumentArray) {
          let result;
          try {

            result = await proceed.apply(context, argumentArray);

          } catch (exception) {

            result = await handler.call(context, exception, argumentArray);
          }
          return result;
        }
      ) || (
        function afterThrowingType(...argumentArray) {
          let result;
          try {

            result = proceed.apply(context, argumentArray);

          } catch (exception) {

            result = handler.call(context, exception, argumentArray);
          }
          return result;
        }
      )
    )
  ) || proceed;
}

Reflect.defineProperty(Function.prototype, 'afterThrowing', {
  configurable: true,
  writable: true,
  value: afterThrowing,
});
</script>

<script>
// mocked module ... 'trace'

  const trace = (() => {

    class TracingSpan {
      #spanTitle;

      constructor(titleValue) {
        this.#spanTitle = String(titleValue);

        console.log(`\n- tracing starts for "${ this.#spanTitle }"`);
      }

      setAttribute(key, value) {
        this[String(key)] = value;

        console.log({ [ String(key) ]: value });
      }
      end() {
        console.log(`# tracing ends for "${ this.#spanTitle }"`);
      }
    }

    async function startActiveSpan(title, tracingCallback) {
      let result;

      if (isFunction(tracingCallback)) {

        result = await tracingCallback(
          new TracingSpan(
            String(title)
          )
        );
      }
      return result;
    }

    return {
      startActiveSpan,
    };

  })();
</script>

<script>
// module ... 'my-service'

class MyService {
  async getSomething() {
    return new Promise(resolve =>
      setTimeout(resolve, 500, 'Hello World!')
    );
  }
  async getSomethingElse() {
    return new Promise(resolve =>
      setTimeout(resolve, 500, 'Hello Something else.')
    );
  }
  async longRunningTask() {
    let r1 = await this.getSomething();
    console.log('longRunningTask ... r1 ...', r1);

    let r2 = await this.getSomethingElse();
    console.log('longRunningTask ... r2 ...', r2);

    return new Promise(resolve =>
      setTimeout(resolve, 500, 'All done.')
    );
  }
}
</script>
```

***Edit** ... regarding the OP's comment ...*

> I understand the idea, thank you @PeterSeliger. But I am fairly intimidated by the verbosity and required complexity to write such system. Tracing as a side effect, should ideally not introduce side effects and breaking existing code. Your prototype implementation tells me, that there is a lot of expertise, added complexity, design and testing necessary to decorate methods that way. Which however helps me, framing my current issue better. – Samuel

In case one does not want to rely on the above posted modifier and glue-code implementing factory based solution, one still can **choose the path of decorated subclassing**.

Then `TracingService` would [**extend**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends#description) `MyService`.

For convenience reasons one would choose for the former constructor's arguments signature an additional `trace` parameter as this constructor's first argument.

The provided `trace` instance would be stored as [private property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_properties).

The prototypal methods of the latter (the extended) class need to be reimplemented by the former (the derived) class, but the implementation would apply delegation via [`super`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super) based method invocations.

Thus, one just needs to write the tracing part, the code-reuse comes with delegation.

```js
class TracingService extends MyService {
  #trace;

  constructor(trace, ...args) {
    super(...args);

    this.#trace = trace;
  }

  async getSomething() {
    return this.#trace.startActiveSpan('getSomething', async (span) => {
      span.setAttribute('specific to getSomething', '1234');

      let result;
      try {
        result = await super.getSomething();
      } catch(exception) {}
      span.end();

      return result;
    });
  }
  async getSomethingElse() {
    return this.#trace.startActiveSpan('getSomethingElse', async (span) => {
      span.setAttribute('specific to getSomething', 'ELSE');

      let result;
      try {
        result = await super.getSomethingElse();
      } catch(exception) {}
      span.end();

      return result;
    });
  }
  async longRunningTask() {
    return this.#trace.startActiveSpan('longRunningTask', async (span) => {
      span.setAttribute('GUID', '1234');

      let result;
      try {
        result = await super.longRunningTask();
      } catch(exception) {}
      span.end();

      return result;
    });
  }
}


(async () => {
  console.log('+++ MyService Test Start +++');

  const service = new MyService();

  const something = await service.getSomething();
  const somethingElse = await service.getSomethingElse();

  const longRunningResult = await service.longRunningTask();

  console.log({
    something, somethingElse, longRunningResult,
  });
  console.log('+++ MyService Test End +++\n\n');


  console.log('\n+++ TracingService Test Start +++');

  const tracingService = new TracingService(trace);

  const somethingTraced = await tracingService.getSomething();
  const somethingElseTraced = await tracingService.getSomethingElse();

  const longRunningResultTraced = await tracingService.longRunningTask();

  console.log({
    somethingTraced, somethingElseTraced, longRunningResultTraced,
  });
  console.log('+++ TracingService Test End +++');
})();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
// mocked module ... 'trace'

  const trace = (() => {

    class TracingSpan {
      #spanTitle;

      constructor(titleValue) {
        this.#spanTitle = String(titleValue);

        console.log(`\n- tracing starts for "${ this.#spanTitle }"`);
      }

      setAttribute(key, value) {
        this[String(key)] = value;

        console.log({ [ String(key) ]: value });
      }
      end() {
        console.log(`# tracing ends for "${ this.#spanTitle }"`);
      }
    }

    async function startActiveSpan(title, tracingCallback) {
      let result;

      if (typeof tracingCallback === 'function') {

        result = await tracingCallback(
          new TracingSpan(
            String(title)
          )
        );
      }
      return result;
    }

    return {
      startActiveSpan,
    };

  })();
</script>

<script>
// module ... 'my-service'

class MyService {
  async getSomething() {
    return new Promise(resolve =>
      setTimeout(resolve, 500, 'Hello World!')
    );
  }
  async getSomethingElse() {
    return new Promise(resolve =>
      setTimeout(resolve, 500, 'Hello Something else.')
    );
  }
  async longRunningTask() {
    let r1 = await this.getSomething();
    console.log('longRunningTask ... r1 ...', r1);

    let r2 = await this.getSomethingElse();
    console.log('longRunningTask ... r2 ...', r2);

    return new Promise(resolve =>
      setTimeout(resolve, 500, 'All done.')
    );
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: What is the point of `getSanitizedTarget`? And why are you passing a `target` at all to these methods instead of using the `this` context? You could always just `.bind()` the context if you needed to.

Comment: I think your `afterFinally` wrapper is broken, since it `return`s exceptions instead of (re)throwing them

Comment: "*the methods are intended to be similar to `bind`*" - yes, it's just that for separation of concerns I would have omitted that feature and called `.bind()` separately. Also it doesn't seem necessary in this example so it's extra weird - but I get you just copied some code you already had lying around.

Comment: It's fine that `afterFinally` always executes the handler, even when an exception occurred, what I think is wrong is that it *handles* the exception and prevents the function from throwing. I would expect it to work just like `try { … } finally { handler() }`. An `Error` should never be `return`ed imo.

Comment: I understand the idea, thank you @PeterSeliger. But I am fairly intimidated by the verbosity and required complexity to write such system. Tracing as a side effect, should ideally not introduce side effects and breaking existing code. Your prototype implementation tells me, that there is a lot of expertise, added complexity, design and testing necessary to decorate methods that way. Which however helps me, framing my current issue better.

Comment: @Bergi ... Regarding the modifier implementations, I have incorporated the points raised in your review into the code.

Comment: @Samuel ... then nothing really prevents you from choosing a solution based on subclassing, decoration and `super` delegation calls. The additionally provided 2nd example code is the least verbose solution one can get from such an approach.