# How to wrap a function (method) with try-catch in modern javascript using decorators (native)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, aws-lambda

- without Typescript `experimentalDecorators: "true"`
- using [proposal-decorators](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators) by TC39

how can I do something like:

```js
class LambdaFunctionExample {

  lambdaResponse = [1, 2 , 3]

  @tryCatchWrapper
  async handler(event) {
    const data = this.lambdaResponse;
    const result = await fetch(...)

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      data,
      result
    };
  }

}
```

and catch errors/events for POC purposes.

Comment: Does the above implementation, once being transpiled, always need to feature the additional functionality applied by the decorator hook?

Comment: A similar problem, solved without decorators but with method-modification, was asked as [_"How to extend/wrap/intercept/decorate a class (with custom functionality like tracing)"_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77798702/how-to-extend-wrap-intercept-decorate-a-class-with-custom-functionality-like-tr)

Answer (score 2):

> for POC purposes, as mentioned

I'm using:

- NodeJS v20
- Typescript 5.3
- using [ESM](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#modules-ecmascript-modules)
- stage 3 TC39 Proporsal Decorators

```js
class LambdaFunctionExample {

  lambdaResponse = [1, 2, 3]

  @tryCatchWrapper
  async handler(event) {
    const data = this.lambdaResponse;
    const result = await fetch(...)

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      data,
      result
    };
  }

}

export const handler =  (event) => new LambdaFunctionExample().handler(event)
```

decorator function:

```js
export function tryCatchWrapper<T>(target: Function, { kind, name, ...context }) {
  if (kind === 'method')
    return async function (this: unknown, ...args: any) {
      try {
        console.log('name', name)
        return await target.call(this, ...args)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('error catched')
        return {}
      }
    }
}
```

and running

```bash
npm start # node index.js (as usual)
```

.tsconfig

```json
  "compilerOptions": {
    // Module Setup
    "target": "ES2022", // as of today, I tried with ESNext and it did't work, so I need to use strictly ES2022
    //"module": "NodeNext", (also optional, but you imporant if you are using ESM)
    //"moduleResolution": "NodeNext", (also optional, but you imporant if you are using ESM)
    ...
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the above solution. +1